# iOS8 notifications token not coming without registering UserNotificationSettings

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, ios8.1

Im behind this issue, I cannot find any other forum talking about it.

The problem is I cannot obtain the device token for remote notifications without accepting the permissions popup first. And here I have a background behind this issue...

Basically, I've been following all the issues using push and local notifications on IOS8. Following Apple official videos and documentation, now push notifications are opted in automatically and permissions popup is only for local notifications and interactive notifications, appearing after setting UserNotificationSettings.

This is what the documentation says about registerRemoteNotifications() method:

*"If you want your app’s remote notifications to display alerts, play sounds, or perform other user-facing actions, you must call the registerUserNotificationSettings: method to request the types of notifications you want to use. If you do not call that method, the system delivers all remote notifications to your app silently."*

Ok, so let's say I want to send silent notifications, the problem is Im calling registerRemoteNotifications but I dont get any callback until I call registerUserNotificationSettings. So there's no way to get a device token and send a push notification.

Does anyone have this same problem and a potential solution?

I just want to get the device token without a permission popup and send push notifications on iOS8 as the documentation explains, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 8, you must register for your remote notifications in this way:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                                                                                               |UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                               |UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Compare that to the iOS 7 way of registering:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

You can combine these two in your app to cover both iOS offerings:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
  UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                                                                                                 |UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                                 |UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

Comment: that's not an answer to my question, did you read my comment about what Apple says in the official documentation?

Comment: ok, so there's no way to get a device token without a permission popup? that's what confuse me, the documentation says you can use silent notifications, probably is not what I want, but at least I want to receive the token without calling registerUserNotificationSettings.

Comment: the documentation says registerUserNotificationSettings is not mandatory if you are going to use silent notifications, this way users dont get the permission popup

Comment: A it is my understanding that the silent notification that they refer to is a notification that does not display (or sound) an OS-level alert to the user. Receiving such an alert still requires permission from the user.

Comment: yes, that's what I understand, anyway even if I want silent notifications, I dont receive the device token calling registerRemoteNofications only, so if I want to send a silent notification now, I don't have any way to do it.

Comment: You will always get the permission popup. Notifications will be silent if you use `UIUserNotificationTypeNone`. This is the way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: mm.. I tried this specific case, and I got the popup anyway, just setting type None

Comment: > *Receiving such an alert still requires permission from the user.* This is not true! You can get token and send silent notifications to user's device if you enable `Remote Notifications` Background Mode capability.

Answer (score 0):

> *I just want to get the device token without a permission popup and send push notifications on iOS8 as the documentation explains, if possible.*

You can only get token without a permission popup if you enable `Remote notifications` under `Capabilities > Background Modes`. Otherwise `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` will not be called.

I remember reading this in Apple's documentation, but can not find it now.